# Jquery по условию

Tags: jquery

Необходимо сделать следующую сортировку

HTML
Сейчас

```
<select id="moId" name="moId">
<option value="0" selected="selected"> </option>
<option value="1">640001 А</option>
<option value="2">640002 М</option>
<option value="3">640003 Т (не действует в 2020)</option>
<option value="4">640004 О (не действует в 2019)</option>
<option value="5">640005 М (не действует в 2021)</option>
<option value="6">640006 Л</option>
</select>
```

Как нужно

```
<select id="moId" name="moId">
<option value="0" selected="selected"> </option>
<option value="1">640001 А</option>
<option value="2">640002 М</option>
<option value="6">640006 Л</option>
<option value="3">640003 Т (не действует в 2020)</option>
<option value="4">640004 О (не действует в 2019)</option>
<option value="5">640005 М (не действует в 2021)</option>
</select>
```

В данном примере сортирует не так как нужно

```
//
    <script>
$(function () {
      var sel = $("#moId"), opts = $("#moId option");
      opts.sort(function (a, b) {
        var re = /\(не действует в 20.*\)$/;
          if (re.test(a.textContent)) {
            if (!re.test(a.textContent)) return 1;
          } else {
            if (re.test(b.textContent)) return -1;
          }
          return 0;
      });
      $.each(opts, function (k, v) {
        sel.append(v);
      });
    });
</script>
//
```

Comment: каков алгоритм сортировки? просто перетащить то, что с годами вниз?

Comment: Ещё приложите html, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему

Comment: У меня в java проекте есть файл txt и там построение через id и идет присоединение с Primary Key БД

Comment: Непонятно зачем сейчас эта информация была))) Приложите html и скажите что нужно в итоге. Какова логика сортировки

Comment: Поправил. Добавил html.

Comment: Кстати, воспроизвожу ваш пример - и он сортирует как надо.

Comment: Может быть проблема на серверной стороне?

Comment: У меня в txt файле не много вразброс, т.е. сортировка идет по id. Даже когда пишу так - var re = /\(640.*\)$/;  то все равно не сортирует

Answer (score 1):

Думаю тут надо немного поменять подход. Не важно, генерируется ли html через сервер или клиент, но:

1. Надо формировать `option` таким образом, чтобы каждый элемент имел `data-` атрибут с ключевывым свойством. например `data-active`, куда заносить данные при формировании html. Например будет `data-active="1"` и `data-active="0"`
2. Применить сортировку на основе атрибута. что гораздо проще, чем выяснять регулярками есть ли какой-то текст или нет.

Comment: Можно на примере

Answer (score 0):

```js
const res = $('#moId option').sort((a,b) => {
    if(/\(не действует в 20.*\)$/.test(a.textContent)) return 0;
  if(!b.textContent.trim()) return 1;
  return -1;
});
$('#moId').html('').append(res)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="moId" name="moId">
<option value="0" selected="selected"> </option>
<option value="1">640001 А</option>
<option value="2">640002 М</option>
<option value="3">640003 Т (не действует в 2020)</option>
<option value="4">640004 О (не действует в 2019)</option>
<option value="5">640005 М (не действует в 2021)</option>
<option value="6">640006 Л</option>
</select>
```

Comment: В данном примере все в разброс пошло